# Wordpress: the_content() not showing

Tags: wordpress, variables, conflict

I installed a plugin called [Admin Guide Dashboard Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-guide-dashboard-widget/). The idea is that it adds a widget to the WordPress Control Panel (the first screen that shows up upon login). On this widget you choose a blog/post category and then every post you write with that category shows up in that widget.

Well it didn't work at all. The widget showed all of my posts. I tried to change the category on the widget, but I just couldn't get it to work so I uninstalled it. Then I realized the the_content() of all my blog posts was gone. I tried to install the plugin again, I tried to change the category I had set for the plugin, nothing worked. I uninstalled. The content part of my posts is still not showing up at all.

Before I installed that plugin I had only created one category, called "Nyheder"
Now I'm not sure if all of my posts were categorized as "Nyheder" or if they were simply uncategorized. I tried unchecking "Nyheder" from my posts but it gets checked again automatically. I don't know if my posts should be uncategorized (if that's even possible) or if the problem lies somewhere else.

The news archive page of the website in question is [here](http://malungos.dk/category/nyheder/). This page actually still shows the content. But if you click on a posts's title to go to its page, you will see that there is no content.

Here is the code on my single.php page, but I really doubt this is the problem.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="pageHead">

</div>
<div id="main2" class="page clearfix">           
    <div id="content" class="threeFourth clearfix" style="width:100%;"><?php get_sidebar(); ?>  
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <div <?php post_class(); ?>>                                        
                <h1 style="display:inline;"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                    <?php 
                        $page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
                        if (substr($page, 1, 14) == "events_listing") {
                            echo "<h2>" . do_shortcode('[events-listing-date]');
                            if(do_shortcode('[events-listing-end-date]') != get_the_modified_date('d-m-Y') ) { 
                                echo " til " . do_shortcode('[events-listing-end-date]') . "</h2>"; 
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                <br>
                <div class="meta clearfix" style="display:inline-block; padding-top: 10px; font-size: 14px;">       
                    <?php _e('Skrevet af', 'themetrust'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?> <?php _e('d.', 'themetrust'); ?> <?php the_time( 'j. F, Y' ) ?><br><br>
                </div>

                <?php edit_post_link(__('Edit Post', 'themetrust'), '<p>', '</p>'); ?>  
                <?php the_content(); ?>                                                                                 
            </div>          

        <?php endwhile; ?>                          
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Assuming that the template above is definitely the one being used (which certainly appears to be the case) there's only a couple of things that I can think of that could cause this. Either somehow the content for the posts has actually been deleted (and what you're seeing on the archive page is actually an excerpt) or that somehow a function has been hooked into the `the_content` filter which returns false. You can try doing a `print_r($wp_filter)` and see what functions are being hooked into `the_content` and then investigate further.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not that advanced in PHP. Where should I put `print_r($wp_filter);` and what should I do with the result?

Comment: You can put the following at the top of `single.php`: `global $wp_filter; print_r($wp_filter);` Then post the results in your question, or if it's really long use [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/) put the link in your question. All that will do is list what functions have been hooked in; we can then see if there's anything that's been hooked into `the_content()` and track it down.

Comment: I hope this helps. I don't think it's the entire thing, but my computer sounded like it was going to explode and pastebin wouldn't let me paste the whole thing: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/b2V1WzSM)

Comment: I forgot how long it can get; I should have told you do do `print_r($wp_filter['the_content']);`. As it stands, not all of it got pasted, but I can see that there's a bunch of functions being hooked in that look like they're to do with some light box plugin. I'd make that suspect number one; try disabling all plugins and see if the content comes back. If it does, then try re-activating the plugins one at a time until you see the content has disappeared. You'll then know which plugin is causing it.

Comment: Everything was working fine before installing that idiotic  Admin Guide Dashboard Widget plugin so that must be the culprit. I can try disabling some other plugins for shits and giggles though. I can also try `print_r($wp_filter['the_content']);`and post the results, but I gotta run right now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it had nothing to do with the plugin, but instead with another change I had made just before installing it. If you look at the code above, I defined a variable called $page. It turns out if I inserted the_content() before that it worked fine, but not after! So I changed the name of the variable to something else and put the_content() back in its place. Voila! I guess there was a conflict with the variable name $page and it somehow affected the_content().